# any one know how to upload file to c drives using java in netbeans?

Tags: java, mysql

I have one file call addLampiran.jsp with the code as below:

```
<div class="field-group row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <label class="TableField" valign="top">Deskripsi Fail</label>
        <input type="text" class="span6 form-control TableField" name="DeskripsiFile" value=""   id="DeskripsiFile" size="50" maxlength="100">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label class="TableField">Nama Fail</label>
        <input name="file" type="file" id="file1" class="span2 form-control TableField" size="50" >
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
         <label></label>
        <br><br>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger span-2 delete " value="Hapuskan" />
    </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="action:processUpdatexx" id="processUpdatexx" >
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    <s:text name="Hantar"/>
</button>
```

I also have one file call xxAction.java file with the code as below:

```
public String processUpdate() {
    try {
        if (getActionErrors().size() > 0 || getActionMessages().size() > 0) {
            return SystemConstants.ACTION_Status.UPDATE_FAIL;
        }
        model.set_operation("updateLampiran");
        serviceFactory.getDramCaseService().update(model);

        addActionMessage(getText("updateSuccess"));
        setId(getModel().getCase_id());
        setAction("lampiran");
        return SystemConstants.ACTION_Status.REFRESH_EDIT;
    } catch (BaseException be) {
        addActionMessage(be.getMessage());
        return SystemConstants.ACTION_Status.UPDATE_FAIL;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        addActionMessage(getText("updateFail"));
        return SystemConstants.ACTION_Status.UPDATE_FAIL;
    } finally {
    }

}
```

So what code I should add into `processUpdate` so that I can upload file into  my c drives and database?

```
CREATE TABLE `file_attachment` (
    `FILE_ID` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci NOT NULL,
    `FILE_PATH` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
    `DESCRIPTION` text,
    `FILE_DATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `CASE_ID` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `MODIFIED_DATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `FILE_NAME` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    `ENTERED_BY` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `ENTERED_DATE` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    `MODIFIED_BY` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`FILE_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Above are the database fields

Comment: And also the ways to download the file

Comment: why do you think your choice of IDE is relevant for any of this? you'll need to use a persistence library. Also, "uploading" is not writing to a DB. adding ASAP to your question really doesn't make most of us want to help you more.

Comment: i am so sorry... this is the first time i try to ask somethings from here

Comment: so did u have any ways  to upload file into c drives?

Comment: uploading implies to a remote server. what you mean is 'downloading'. add a link to the file. do you know how persistence works in Java?

Comment: wht i really  want is the uploading part ... after upload it can be click the name from the list of file and view or download the file

Comment: no. In your entire explanation, there is no mention of uploading, just storing the data in a database (persistence) and loading it on your local hard drive (download, or just a save, depending on where you store your db)

Comment: "So what code I should add into processUpdate so that I can upload file into my c drives and database?"  here i ask about how to upload file into c drives

Comment: putting files on your c drive is NOT uploading. to download a file, you add a link to a file that already exists: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727371/how-to-download-attachment-file-from-jsp
to put data in your database, use jpa/hibernate/any other persistence library/implementation

Comment: So what it call ?? I need the ways to put file into c drives by using the input fields

Comment: have you checked the link I posted? Please don't wait until somebody decides to write custom code for you

Comment: Try to read [Uploading files](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/)